# Delphi Try except block dodging its purpose

Tags: list, delphi, try-except, delphi-12-athens

I made a func to check if a TObjectList is empty because the .OwnsObjects didnt work and just using [0] raised a error so i made this

```
function IsEmptyList(List:TObjectList<TImage>):Boolean;
begin
  try
    List[0];
    result:=False;
  except
    result:=True;
  end;
end;
```

I put the List[0] in thy try block and in theory it should raise the empty exception as normal and run the except block but instead it raises the exception and crashes the app.
[image]

[image]

I expected the code to run the except block but it crashed

Comment: Why don't you use the ``Count`` property for checking for an empty list!? ``if MyList.Count = 0 then``

Comment: In addition, the application didn't "crash". The dialog box you see is from the debugger, not from your app. If you run your app outside the debugger, you will see no error message. When you click "Fortsetzen", you see how your app behaves. With the `try..except`, your app will not show any error message. Without the `try..except`, your app will show its own error message as soon as you click `Fortsetzen`.

Comment: But as Delphi Coder already mentioned, this is a very bad example of `try..except`. Don't use exceptions for expected things like this.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand The app then keeps on spamming error message with access violation if i click on "Fortsetzen" I also tried to run it without the debugger and it still raised the error

Comment: Access violation errors are severe errors. You should never ever have such errors. But these errors are coming from some other part of your app. Please note that simply eating the exception will continue execution (in this case, higher up in the call stack). So the routine calling `IsEmptyList` will continue to run (even though there was an error!), and the routine calling that routine, and so on. If you eat an exception, it is your responsibility to make sure that you handle the condition correctly.

Comment: Where are the AV errors located? Probably in another part of the code we can not see!?

Comment: For example: `Dog := CreateDog; Dog.Bark`. If `CreateDog` raises an exception internally, `Dog` will not get assigned and `Dog.Bark` will not run. But if you eat all exceptions in `CreateDog`, execution will continue. Whatever `CreateDog` returns (`nil`, a dangling pointer, a random pointer, etc.) will be assigned to `Dog` and `Dog.Bark` will cause memory corruption, AVs, etc.

Comment: And this is not related specifically to returned values: `CreateZoo; UseZoo;`. If `CreateZoo` raises an exception (and you don't eat it), `UseZoo` will not run. If you eat all exceptions in `CreateZoo`, `UseZoo` will still run even though there may not be a properly set up zoo! Result: memory corruption, AVs, etc.

Comment: I used the IsListEmpty func in an if statement with a list i know i used := TObjectList<TImage>.Create(); on so i dont know why this list specifically would not work because i have other lobj lists that work

Comment: @DelphiCoder i used the .Count=0 u said i should use and it works but i still dont understand why the try block doesnt run the except block

Comment: @LuanZekiri I recommend you read [Catch Me If You Can](https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2018/10/catch-me-if-you-can.html) and [Catch Me If You Can - Part II](https://dalijap.blogspot.com/2023/12/catch-me-if-you-can-part-ii.html) articles by Dalija Prasnikar in order to better understand why sometimes `Except` block of `try..except` statement is not executed.

Comment: @SilverWarior Those blog posts are valid for non Windows platforms. On Windows catching exceptions works as expected.

Comment: You already got plenty of good advices in previous comments. However, if you want a real answer why your code is not working properly, then you really need to show [mcve] The code you posted here, while it is not the best practice as you are trying to access invalid memory, should catch the exception and return Boolean value. If you edit the question and provide proper [mcve] we could tell you more.

Comment: We told you already the error message is shown because of the running debugger

Comment: Creating and deleting objects means allocating and deallocating memory from heap. To speedup such operations default memory manager in Delphi uses cache. So if you have done List[0].Free and soon after that call IsEmptyList, exception may not be raised, because your code reads data from cache, that happened to not been reused yet. If you want to always get exceptions in such situations and do not care about speed of your app (for example you are debugging a bug), than you can use FastMM in FullDebug mode or SafeMM: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zaOqK7aDcuI